# How to set group name when exporting pyvista mesh to wavefront obj

Tags: python, wavefront, pyvista

I am generating some cylinder meshes from some csv data and adding them to a PyVista plotter, using this I then export them to an '.obj' file using the `export_obj` method. The problem is I want to associate a group name with each mesh inside the obj file so I can use that information later, however the exporter seems to assign a random name like `grp123` to each mesh.

```
IDS = df[ID_FIELD].values
p = pv.Plotter()
length = len(IDS)
for index, id in enumerate(IDS[: NUM_TO_GENERATE]):
    print(f"Making Column {index}/{length}", end=", ")
    data = dfa.loc[dfa[ID_FIELD] == id]
    print(f"NUM ROWS: {len(data)}")
    print(id)

    x = float(df.loc[df[ID_FIELD] == id][C1])
    z = float(df.loc[df[ID_FIELD] == id][C2])
    for row in data.values:
        height = float(row[C3]) - float(row[C4])
        cyl = pv.Cylinder(height=height, center=(
        x, float(row[FROM_COLUMN]) + height/2, z), direction=(0, 1.0, 0))
        p.add_mesh(cyl, name=id, label=id)

p.add_axes()
p.export_obj("data.obj")
```

So yeah basically help associating a name with each group inside the obj file would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyVista uses [`vtkOBJExporter()`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkOBJExporter.html#details) under the hood to print out OBJ files. The VTK class has suspiciously few public methods, and none that seem relevant for naming groups.

The smoking gun is [in the implementation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/8fffe84bef8be2133e8a3da28353d2e4e76fc423/IO/Export/vtkOBJExporter.cxx#L299-301):

```cpp
  // write out a group name and material
  fpObj << "\ng grp" << idStart << "\n";
  fpObj << "usemtl mtl" << idStart << "\n";
```

This looks very much like something that is hard-coded in VTK itself (and using integer `idStart` indices to label everything in the output file), in other words the `vtkOBJExporter()` doesn't support defining custom group labels, I'm afraid. Since PyVista uses this exporter, you won't be able to work around this within the library.